# PostgreSql cursorfunction for unique id

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to Create a cursor on cartesian product/join as below, it gives an error

```
create or replace function som1() returns integer as $$
declare
rCur cursor for  (select*  from t1);
 er route%rowtype;

begin
for er in
 select  route_id, location, happy from t1, t2 where exams.pid = route.pid 
 loop
 end loop;
return 4;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
select som1();
```

Comment: Help us help you - please [edit] your post with the error you're getting

Comment: Also, let us know what are you trying to achieve. Your return value from function makes no sense in relation to the cursor and loops.

Comment: actually i'm not trying to achieve anything..i wanted to learn the syntax how we create cartesian product/join on cursor..im returning just integer so i know there is no error in it..no other result..any help will be appreciated

Comment: You best use a `CROSS JOIN` to write a cartesian product. This is independent of whether you use the query in a cursor or not.

Comment: could you provide simple example?